# How do we know the representation for $n_2 \lt n_1$ has less bases?

Tags: number-theory

Given that we know the following is true:

$n = \sum_{j=0}^{s} c_j 3^j, c_s \ne 0, c_j \in \{-1,0,1\}$

We are to determine the least number of weights to weigh any integral number of pounds up to 80 pounds if one is allowed to put weights in both pans of a balance.

The answer is clearly 5 weights (1 lb, 3 lb, 9 lb, 27 lb, 81 lb), since we can represent $80 < 81 = 3^4$

But my question is as follows, and is vital to the proof (I assume? Is it?).  Regardless, I'd like to know:  How do we know that some number less than $80$, such as $79$ doesn't require more than $5$ weights to be represented?

How can we prove that every number less than 80 requires either 5 weights or less to be represented, essentially?

I would normally use proof by induction, but as you can see, my above statement isn't valid for all integers, only integers below 82.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more?  I'm still unsure about how I'd use contradiction in this case.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401561/every-integers-from-1-to-121-can-be-written-as-5-powers-of-3 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039528/least-number-of-weights-required-to-weigh-integer-weights

Comment: Observe: every number up to $121$ can be written as $a+3b+9c+27d+81e$ with $a,b,c,d$ between $0$ and $2$, inclusive, and $e$ equal $0$ or $1$. Then observe that $2x=(-1)x+(1)(3x)$, so you can replace any $2$ with a $1$ and a $-1$, starting at the bottom and working your way up. Try it for $79$!

Comment: So, what do you think, Jason?

Comment: I'm still having a little bit of trouble understanding this.  I've decided to stop learning number theory and learn about the basics of proofs/math logic first.